# knex how to check if current migration is the latest or not

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I am using knex for postgres migration version control. The basic idea is: 
every time when node starts, it checks if current database migration is the latest or not. If not, then apply the latest one by `knex.migrate.latest().then(....)`.

For example, I have a `init.js` migration file which is my current db version. Then I submit a new one `newMigration.js` and re-start server. I want the node to find the new migration and apply it.

I know there is a `.currentVersion` function to get the current db migration version, but how can node know the newly added migration (version)?

Please advise! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's documented [here](http://knexjs.org/#Migrations-latest).

i have something like this in one of my projects:

```
// iniciando o servidor, mas antes verificando qual é a do banco
console.log("(1/3) running [knex.migrate.latest()]");
knex.migrate.latest().then(function () {
  console.log("(2/3) running [knex.seed.run()]");
  return knex.seed.run(); // XXX converter os seeds em migrations
}).then(function () {
  var s = "(3/3) app ready. Listening port: ";
  console.log(s + port + ", addr: " + (addr ? addr : "0.0.0.0"));
  http.listen(port, addr);
});
```

that way everytime node restarts it checks for newer migrations and run them.

only when this process ends i start to listen http requests